Garmin 695/696 joystick removal
I have a Garmin 696 with a faulty joystick. I have a parts unit that I'd like to swap the joystick with, however upon disassembling the units, I can see how to disconnect the signal lines from the joystick but not how to remove the joystick itself.

Removing the four screws surrounding it does not loosen it and I believe that the three nuts on top are to seal the joystick itself so I haven't touched those. The entire assembly has a little play to the left and right so it's probably not screwed in. But how it's attached is a bit of a mystery to me.
Does anyone know how to do this? Google has not produced any useful results.

Can you remove the PCB and look on the other side?

I can't. The joystick prevents removal of the PCB.

I find it difficult to see how this fits into aviation as defined in the help centre. On a purely practical basis you might find you get better answers on [electronics.se]

@Hawkman Did you remove the knob on the front side? In such a case, can you post a picture on the front? There's probably some mechanical movement to do to detach it

I did yes. The knob popped right off and there is nothing behind it to unscrew.
It’s an aviation GPS. I assumed possibly incorrectly that more aviation people would be familiar with it. No non-aviation GPS has this joystick.

Maybe those three nuts will take off the black cover for the joystick and then you could have more access? Also what do you mean the joystick prevents the removal of the PCB?
